# How to fix Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, server, promise

After reading up on this topic for the last 2.5 hours I cant determine how to fix my: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client issue, but I think it has to do with the below code at the bottom especially the code is in bold.

Any help or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

```
app.post("/api/tracking/retrieve", (req, res) => {

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
// before all the iterations

    const trackingCodes = ['EZ6000000006', 'EZ4000000004'];
    const carrierCodes = ['UPS', 'UPS'];

    trackingCodes.forEach((trackingCode) => {
        carrierCodes.forEach((carrierCode) => {
            const tracker = new api.Tracker({
                tracking_code: trackingCode,
                carrier: carrierCode
            })

            tracker.save().then(function (data) {

                table = 'tracking_table';
                col = ['user_id', 'tracking_number'];
                val = [user_id, tracker.tracking_code];

            **// !ISSUE: :: ::: :::: ::::: :::::: ::::::: //**

                main.create(table, col, val, function (data) {
                      res.send(JSON.stringify({
                        id: "",
                        user_id: user_id,
                        tracking_number: data.tracking_code
                    })); // replace this for your res.json()
                });
            }

            )
                .catch(error => {
                    // handle errors
                    console.log('There has been an error with your submission.')
                });
        })
    })
res.end()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kiran Mathew has answered, the res.json() are called again and again inside for loop which is why 'cannot set headers after response sent' occurs.

You could have a result array '**trackingNumbers**' to store all tracking_number and later exiting from the loop, sent a single response.

```
app.post("/api/tracking/retrieve", (req, res) => {
const trackingCodes = ["EZ6000000006", "EZ4000000004"];
  const carrierCodes = ["UPS", "UPS"];
  const trackingNumbers = [];

  trackingCodes.forEach(trackingCode => {
    carrierCodes.forEach(carrierCode => {
      const tracker = new api.Tracker({
        tracking_code: trackingCode,
        carrier: carrierCode
      });

      tracker
        .save()
        .then(function(data) {
          table = "tracking_table";
          col = ["user_id", "tracking_number"];
          val = [user_id, tracker.tracking_code];

          // !ISSUE: :: ::: :::: ::::: :::::: ::::::: //**

          main.create(table, col, val, function(data) {
            // res.json({
            //   id: "",
            //   user_id: user_id,
            //   tracking_number: data.tracking_code
            // });

            trackingNumbers.push(data.tracking_code);
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // handle errors
          console.log("There has been an error with your submission.");
        });

      res.json({
        id: "",
        user_id: user_id,
        tracking_number: trackingNumbers
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is you are calling res.json() in an iterative loop.

You should call that only once since

> res.json() implements res.write(),res.setHeaders() and res.end() under the hood,
>   which means once res.end() is called it ends the request and cannot send anymore.

You are better off writing the responses using

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // before all the iterations
res.send(JSON.stringify({key:"value"})); // replace this for your res.json()
res.end() // after iterations
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check this out later.

Comment: I added in your code and am still receiving the error. I have updated the above code to reflect your recommended changes.